# Refresh datagridview same time as i wrote on Search/Filter tab vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need an help.

I have a search tab on my program in vb.net.
That works, but only shows me the information after i press the button, and i want to show me in same time as i wrote.

There is my code.

```
    Public Sub search()

    con.Open()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from livrosescola where NomeLivro Like'%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", con)
    ds.Fill(dt)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
    DataGridView1.Refresh()

    ds.Dispose()
    con.Close()



End Sub
```

If you didn't understand what i want, theres a link where you can see what i want.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKY2RaZHi6Q > min 6:20 if you notice the datagridview refreshes at same time as he write.

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you just call the search routine after you write?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you call your function search() in the button.Click something like:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    search()
End Sub
```

Wath you need to do is use the KeyPress or TextChanged event of your TextBox1:

```
Public Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    search()
End Sub
```

On the other hand, execute a query for every key presed in your textbox could be a bit rough for you database.

What I suggest you (if your table doesn´t have much more than... say 50000 rows), it's fill a DataTable with all the rows and then when you need filter you do it over the DataTable instead of the database.

Comment: you were much more detailed than my post.

Comment: I already had the button1_click, but the keypress worked for me. Thank you sir.